# Angular/Node.js: Create subdomain on aws server from code end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, subdomain

I am working on a project in which i have to create sub domains dynamically when user enters prefix as their sub domain at my website. 
i used *diet.js* and  *express-subdomain* both are working fine on my localhost but on aws server both firing error.

```
This site can’t be reached

subdomain.xx.xx.xxx.xx’s server DNS address could not be found.
Search Google for subdomain162 3000
```

Is there any solution for this issue?

Update with more clarification.

I have database of modules having names(which i want to use as sub domain)
So if someone who created that module on my website than he can be access website as module.example.com
For example blogspot.com website works

Comment: The actual problem you are describing is unclear, so it is difficult to know what the variables are.  How do you actually create the subdomains dynamically on AWS?  And how do you do it on localhost?  And what does `dig` show you about the status of the DNS?

Comment: I have database of modules having names(which i want to use as sub domain) So if someone who created that module on my website than he can be access website as module.example.com For example blogspot.com website works

Comment: Understood.  But what are you *doing* to make that work?  How is your code modifying DNS?

Comment: i don't want to modify DNS, Is there any option when i map domain(eg. www.xyz.com ) with name servers and if any sub domain (eg. www.sub.xyz.com) hit than it also points to same name servers.!

Answer (score 0):

DNS has propagation time check the domain on [What's My DNS](https://www.whatsmydns.net/)

It depends on TTL time and how often AWS master zones refresh.

e.g.
If your TTL is 3600 it can take up to an hour.

Comment: You are thinking it in wrong way, I have database with each module's name(which would be the sub domain). So i have run website differently for each name. Have you got this?